# Simplify usage of Vuetify tooltip

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to simplify the usage of the Vuetify tooltip.
Instead of this:

```js
<v-tooltip bottom>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
    <v-icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">mdi-home</v-icon>
  </template>
  <span>Tooltip</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

I would like something like this:

```js
<v-icon tooltip="Tooltip" tooltip-position="bottom">mdi-home</v-icon>
```

As far as I know, Vuetify doesn't have this ability, but can it be achieved with a custom plugin or something else?

Comment: This feature is not yet present in Vuetify but they are adding it in Vuetify 3.0. You can check out the discussion (https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9610)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom tooltip component by puttin a wrapper on this vuetify tooltip, passing all the content as props and displaying accordingly.

OR a simple solution would be use some external library e.g.

https://github.com/hekigan/vue-directive-tooltip

`vue-directive-tooltip` has the same syntax as you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the BootstrapVue directive, which is already part of the library.

```
<template>
  <div class='main'>
    <b-button v-b-tooltip.hover.right="'Tooltip!'" variant="primary"
      >hover</b-button
    >
  </div>
</template>
```

This directive can be used in vuetify components like v-icon or v-botton or any other.

You need a CSS code like the one below:

```
<style>
.main {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to be for BootstrapVue, not Vuetify...

Comment: My answer, is an alternative to the question, which was about something on vuetify, what can I do if my alternative is bootstrapvue?